# How to display column as well as grouped by in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
Create table #test (Type nvarchar(250), DayCount int, WeekCount int)

insert into #test values ('A/C', 1346, 8095)
insert into #test values ('Cooler', 13, 36)
insert into #test values ('Table Fan', 0, 5)
insert into #test values ('Ceiling Fan', 186, 4507)
```

Output should be:

```
Type        DayCount  WeekCount  TotDayCount  TotWeekCount
----------------------------------------------------------
A/C          1346     8095        1445         12643
Cooler       13       36          1445         12643
Table Fan    0        5           1445         12643
Ceiling Fan  186      4507        1445         12643
```

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: I guess `TotDayCount=1445`  should be `1545`.

Answer (score 0):

Use sub queries:

```
SELECT Type,        
       DayCount,
       WeekCount,
       TotDayCount =  ( SELECT SUM(DayCount)
                        FROM Test ),
       TotWeekCount = ( SELECT SUM(WeekCount)
                        FROM Test )
FROM  Test
```

[**Sql-fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84b0e/2/0)

You don't need to be afraid that these queries are executed for every row. The SQL-Server optimizer is smart enough to calculate it only once.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on a fairly modern version of SQL Server, you can use `SUM OVER`:

```
select
t1.*,
sum(daycount) over () as DayTotal,
sum(weekcount) over () WeekCount
from
test t1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/74bae/1)

Here's more information about the `over` clause:
[Clicky!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)